# background image not resize properly on media query?

Tags: css

this is my code:

```
      .review-dots-teal {
        background-image: url('./scss/img/dots-teal@1x.png');
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 760px;
        z-index: -1;
        height: 368px;
        width: 368px;
        @include mediaQuery(992px) {
         width: 268px;
         height:268px;
        }
        @include mediaQuery(768px) {
         width: 168px;
         height:168px;
        }
      }
```

The image is like this when it's not resized by media query:
[image]
but when the media query is applied, with height and weight reduced, it looks like this:

[image]

The image didn't became small? the dots are same size, how do i make the image fit the set width and height by media query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `width:100%` to image

```
 img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

This will ensure that the image will always occupy full width of the container.

Check the snippet in full screen mode and mobile mode

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
  .container {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUOYB.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Max width: 368 px;
Width: 100%

Same for height and for media query also